# In Eclipse, how can I change the automatic highlighting colors? (I made a Screenshot of what I mean)

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, settings, preferences

Here is the screenshot. How can I change the color of the light gray highlightning? Disabling it would be fine as well.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7iepp.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing are apparently marked occurrences, that is to say, when the cursor is over an identifier, the other occurrences of that field or method are highlighted. The highlight stays active until the cursor is over another identifier (for longer than a second or so). You can toggle the marking of occurrences by pressing Shift+Alt+O, it's also a toggle button in the "Editor Presentation" toolbar.

If you like the marking of occurrences but not its appearance, you can customise that too: In the preferences, navigate to **General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations**, then select "Occurrences" from the list of annotation types. You can then, for example, select the background colour on the right.